# Different types of build using CruiseControl.NET

Tags: build-automation, cruisecontrol.net

I would like to know what kinds of builds (i.e for example and learning) does one have.

I currently set up nightly build triggered on changes..

Should I have a different server for ci builds or different config blocks???

Please give ideas or samples on how you maintain CI and nightly build in config

Comment: A tip - answers are not the place for a conversation, as they aren't always shown chronologically (in fact, they're normally ranked by votes). Try using comments.

Answer (score 1):

We use one build machine (a slightly older desktop pc at the moment, going to be in the server rack soon), with multiple project blocks in the configuration.

We have several main projects:

- Debug (triggered automatically every hour)
- Test(integration & unit tests) (triggered once a day)
- Release (manually triggered, also does the integration and unit tests)

this seems to work well for our team of 12, however it would depend on your team size, release frequency and whether you do nightly builds for beta users.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use different working folders for each build type (unless you don't mind that the build types will overwrite each other) you can effectively have as many CCNet project configurations per product on one server.

At work, one of our build servers builds 4 different products, each with at least 2 builds - one nightly and one CI build. Our CI builds trigger on changes every 15 minutes and the nightly build triggers on a schedule only if there have been changes.